# How do I make a UIImageView fill a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

This is my first post, so if there is something that I should do differently, please let me know!

I'm making a photo app, where the I want the photos to fill the UITaleViewCells, and the Cells to expand to fit the images.

---

I've been struggling to make it work, I've googled everything I can thing of, watched a few youtube videos, but I can't find any that work with UIImageView's. Here is the code I'm working with right now:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

On the UIImageView I have these constraints:
`Bottom Margin`, `Top Margin`, `Trailing Margin` and `Leading Margin`, when I run my app I get this really weird space at the top and the bottom of my images.

---

Here is some screenshots:

[image: Full Main.storyboard screenshot]

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

Comment: try setting  automaticallAdjustsScrollViewInsets to false in your viewdidload method.ex-: tableview.automaticallAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false.

Comment: @TusharSharma Where would I put that code? in `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`, where the code in my question is, or `viewDidLoad()`? And is the `view` first letter supposed to be capitalized.

Comment: in viewDidLoad() add tableView.automaticallAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: @TusharSharma OK, but I get this error: `Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'automaticallAdjustsScrollViewInsets'`

Comment: What is name of your table?

Comment: @TusharSharma I'm not sure what you mean by the name of it, but I believe it is tableView. I can post a screenshot of my code if that helps!

Comment: try self.automaticallAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false once.

Comment: @TusharSharma Sorry for the delayed response. I tried it, and I figured out that you left the "y" off "automatically", so I retried both suggestions, but it doesn't change anything. I would love more suggestions/ideas!

Comment: Change your contentMode to `Aspect Fill` instead of `Aspect Fit`

Comment: @Rikh That removes the space between the tableview cells, but now the images are clipped off the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well i suggest you to try with UICollectionView for this because for such layouts its better to use Collection View instead Table Views, try this (tempArr means your image array),

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // create a cell size from the image size, and return the size

    let picHeight = tempArr[indexPath.row].valueForKey("imgHeight") as! String
    let picWidth = tempArr[indexPath.row].valueForKey("imgWidth") as! String
    var picHeightFloat :CGFloat!
    var picWidthFloat :CGFloat!

    if let n = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(picHeight) {
        picHeightFloat = CGFloat(n)
    }
    if let q = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(picWidth) {
        picWidthFloat = CGFloat(q)
    }

    let imageSize = CGSize(width: picWidthFloat, height: picHeightFloat)


    return imageSize
}
```

Comment: I will take a look into it, I haven't worked with UICollectionView before.

Comment: I've done same sort of apps and i've started with table views too but then with the requirements and the ease of code i realize its better to go with collection views. Its really easy with collection views. Give it a try.

Comment: I have figured it out using thee UITableView, but I will keep the CollectionViews in mind for future projects. Thank you for your time and suggestions!